# Pass regex to command while using zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards, arguments

In bash I can do the following:

`apt install blabla*`

But in zsh I get

`zsh: no matches found: blabla*`

Unless there is a file in the current directory called blablabla.

This also causes issues with deleting files *within* a folder without deleting the folder itself if it requires sudo access to write to.

How do I make zsh pass regex to a command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that filename globbing patterns are not regular expressions.  They are *similar* but the globbing pattern `blabla*` would match names starting with the string `blabla`, while the regular expression `blabla*` would match strings containing the sub-string `blabl`, possibly followed by zero or more `a` characters.

To pass the string `blabla*` as an argument to `apt install` without having the shell trying and failing to use it as a *filename globbing pattern*, quote it:

```
apt install 'blabla*'
```

The `zsh` shell has, by default, the `NOMATCH` shell option set, which corresponds to the `failglob` shell option in `bash` (which is *not* set by default in that shell).  This will make the shell fail with a diagnostic message when a globbing pattern does not match anything.  You could also obviously turn this shell option off (with `unsetopt NOMATCH` or `setopt NO_NOMATCH`), but that would not help you in the case of using `sudo` to delete files that you don't have access to.

To expand a filename pattern such as `bla/*`, a shell is needed (the `rm` command can't expand shell globbing patterns by itself, and very few commands can, so `sudo rm -rf bla/*` would not work even if you stopped the current shell from even trying to expand the patten by quoting it). Since you may not have access to read the names in the directory `bla`, that shell has to be executing as a user that *does* have access to read the names in the directory, e.g. root.  We can execute a shell as the root user by using `sudo`.

To delete all files and directories within a directory that you don't have access to, using `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'rm -rf directoryname/*'
```

Note that this would not remove hidden names, for that, use something like

```
sudo bash -O dotglob -c 'rm -rf directoryname/*'
```

or

```
sudo zsh -c 'rm -rf directoryname/*(D)'
```

or

```
sudo find directoryname -mindepth 1 -delete
```

or, using standard `find`,

```
sudo find directoryname -depth ! -path directoryname -exec rm -rf {} +
```

The first three commands relies on the globbing being carried out by the `sh -c`, `bash -c` or `zsh -c` shells that the root user is running, while the last two commands simply does not use filename globbing at all.  The variations with `find` would also support removing a directory with many thousands of files (this may generate an "argument list too long" error if globbing is attempted).

Another option, if you really want to delete *all* the contents of a directory, is to simple delete the whole directory with

```
sudo rm -rf directoryname
```

and then recreate it with the correct ownership and permissions.

Comment: What's missing from this is an explanation that `failglob` is clearly off in the questioner's Bourne Again shell, and `nomatch` is clearly on in the questioner's Z shell.

Comment: @JdeBP Added, thanks.

Comment: I would prefer solutions that remain within zshell without requiring a switch to bash or sh

Comment: Eg bash I can sudo rm -rf /bla/* but zsh errors out

Comment: @linuxandria There are several solutions in my answer to your second issue that does not invoke any other shell (the last two `find` commands).

Comment: @linuxandria To expand `/bla/*` you need a shell. If the current shell is run by _you_, then you can't expand the pattern as you don't have access. This is why I give a few examples that invokes a shell as root to expand the pattern.

Comment: @linuxandria The alternate to all my variations of solutions is obviously `sudo chmod -R o+rwx bla` followed by `rm -rf bla/*` and `sudo chmod -R o-rwx bla` or similar, but that's terribly unsafe.  You could also just `sudo rm -rf bla` and then recreate the directory with `sudo mkdir bla`.  But none of the things in this comment tokes the original owner and permissions of the `bla` directory into account.

Comment: @Kusalananda the ' ' was what I was missing. Previously I just launched bash when I needed that functionality. Only frustration is still rm files/* which works fine in bash without needing to remember a lengthy find command. It's also not an option to delete the directory and I can't own it a system user has to.

Comment: @linuxandria If the directory is _readable_ by you, `sudo rm -rf files/*` would work in any shell. If you can't read the directory listing, then it would not work in `bash` either as the `files/*` pattern is expanded by the current shell running under your username.

Comment: @Kusalananda actually no. Works fine in bash and I don't own the directory in any way